# Express JS | Setting Cache Header on JPEG files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, caching

I am trying to set up Cache-Control on my Static image files. I am able to set this header on HTML and JS files:

[image: JS file cache]

But with JPEG files:

[image: JPEG Cache]

When serving my static files I am using MaxAge, CacheControl, and immutable:

```
app.use(
    express.static("./build", {
      maxAge: cacheTime,
      extensions: ["html"],
      cacheControl: true,
      immutable: true,
    })
  );
```

As well as trying to set the cache on every request using:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    (res as Response).set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31557600");
    (res as Response).set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    next();
  });
```

The thing is this seems to work on my LocalHost... I see the image cache-control. But when deployed on a NameCheap Server using Cpanel Node JS application I am getting the results above. Can anyone see where my mistake is or no the difference in why one is caching and the other not? Or any hints on how to figure this out?

Comment: Express server config looks correct. However I could see that the jpg assets are served by Apache and not express server. I see a  response header "Server: Apache" which makes me suspect, it's not served by express. Usually express server have a response header x-powered-by: Express by default
https://repl.it/repls/ContentCadetblueOs  
https://contentcadetblueos--five-nine.repl.co/image1.jpg

Comment: @nithin Thank you. Added caching to my .htaccess file and we are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The express server configuration was correct. Because Apache was serving the images and not express, I added the following to my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|webp)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```